# How to switch from metro to desktop in MSVC++2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winsock2

I've been working with boost in msvc++2010. Recently, I tried the new version of msvc++(2012 ultimate), and since then I cannot build my applications 'cause it doesn't include some headers like winsock2. Some sites say the new window's app mode, metro style, can't use these libs and headers, and then I've been tried to switch from this metro style to old desktop. Can someone help-me?

Answer (score 5):

My installation of Visual Studio 2012 Express does have this header, so this seems not to be a matter of Visual Studio versions. The path is:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\WinSock2.h
```

Make sure, that you've specified valid paths in include search directory. You can also install the full [Windows 8 Platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx).

Finally, make sure, that you've chosen **Win32** application in the project wizard. The newest version of Visual Studio is as capable of building native Win32 code as any other.

Comment: What I have to do to make the msvc++ to be able to find this by its own?

Comment: I'm using boost, the problem comes from some header in it.